# Fancybox3 ACF repeater. URL strip out from the caption field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

The gallery works correct as it should but every time that I had a link/url on the caption field it breaks the gallery.
Surely should be something around here .html(); thats is filtering the html tags.

ACF repeater:

```
<?php
    if( have_rows('gallery') ):
?>

  <div class="row">

    <?php
        while( have_rows('gallery') ) : the_row();
        $image = get_sub_field('image');
        $caption = get_sub_field('caption');
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 pl-2">
    <figure class="image-holder">
      <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>" data-fancybox="images">
        <img class="gallery-img" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
        <figcaption><?php echo $caption; ?></figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    </div>

    <?php
      endwhile;
          else :
      //echo "No images selected";
    ?>

  </div>

<?php
  endif;
?>
```

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $( '[data-fancybox="images"]' ).fancybox({
 caption : function( instance, item ) {
    return $(this).find('figcaption').html();
  },

  toolbar  : false,
  smallBtn : true,
  iframe : {
    preload : false
  },

  beforeShow: function() {
    $('.caption--image').remove();
 },
 afterShow: function() {
    var caption = $(".fancybox-caption"),
        innerCaption = caption.clone().addClass('caption--image');

    $(".fancybox-slide--current .fancybox-content").append(innerCaption);
    caption.not('.caption--image').addClass('caption--bottom');
  }
 });
});
```

The test can be executed on this codepen:
codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/aaerxw

If we had a html tag such link inside the figcaption the gallery stops to work

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry. You're saying your $caption contains a `<a>` tag, and this is breaking the gallery? Is it a script problem or a PHP problem? I don't see anything in the script that looks at the figcaption. What precisely is the error you're getting? What is $caption when it breaks?

Comment: @Rup The caption works if is plain text. If I had a html tag such <a> it breaks the gallery

Comment: OK. Does it break it with a server-side error? Or a script error? Or does it just look wrong? Or something else?

Comment: @Rup try to add <a> inside the figcaption on this pen https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/aaerxw  and see what happens

Comment: @Rup are you "follow" now ? thank you

Comment: Yes, the codepen is very useful (although it does prove that this isn't a WordPress problem). However it still would have been helpful if you'd explained what you meant by breaking.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that fancybox is binding itself to the outermost <a>s, and now accidentally picking up the inner <a> too. In the broken case you'll see that the previous and next arrows stop on any image with a link in the caption twice. I'd guess this isn't supported by fancybox.

Comment: It is supported example http://james2013.batcave.net/fancy/demo/test1.htm. As I mentioned on my question the gallery is working and therefore is not mainly an issue with WordPress is an issue with fancybox3 working with ACF repeater. @Rup

Comment: That example doesn't have an <a> tag in a figcaption on the page for the link, it's got the whole caption in a data attribute and reads it from that. You could copy that model instead, or you could fix figcaption to only bind to the correct <a>s and not your <figcaption><a>.